# Nagios: bash is missing

Tags: bash, shell-scripting, nagios, nrpe

I'm monitoring NTP server with nagios and nrpe, at the nagios server, when I get the following error:
Service Status  UNKNOWN
Status information  I am missing an important component : bash

The plugin is: http://archive.groundworkopensource.com/groundwork-opensource/trunk/monitor-core/nagios/plugins-contrib/check_procr.sh

The output when I do `bash -x check_procr.sh` is:

```
+ myself=check_procr
+ verify_dep
+ needed='bash cut egrep expr grep let ps sed sort tail test tr wc'
++ echo bash cut egrep expr grep let ps sed sort tail test tr wc
+ for i in '`echo $needed`'
+ type bash /dev/null
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo 'I am missing an important component : bash'
I am missing an important component : bash
+ echo 'Cannot continue, sorry, try to find the missing one...'
Cannot continue, sorry, try to find the missing one...
+ exit 3
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the function `verify_dep()` so that the line

```
  type $i > /dev/null 2>&1 /dev/null
```

is changed to

```
  type $i > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Afterwards, it should work. The original line was wrong and always resulted in an error.